# Numerically integrate function with sudden jumps

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity

I want to integrate the function

`Log [ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(
     x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))]`

for x,t and y between -50 and 50. This function jumps suddenly at x=-y, so the code

`NIntegrate[SetPrecision[Log [ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-(x + y)^2/(2 0.00001)], 10], {x, -50, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, WorkingPrecision -> 10 ]`

gives the following output:

```
NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral.
```

Then, i thought about partitioning the region, which is a square, in 6 sub-regions, as follows:

`NIntegrate[
  SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 0}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, 0, -x}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -x, 50}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -x, 0}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -50, -x}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10]`

Mathematica is able to compute this integral and gives the answer 129869.8932. But, I decided to compute the same thing using other code:

`NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log [ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, 0, -x}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, -50, 0}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -x, 50}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log [(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -x, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10] + NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(50^2)/Log[ (x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 0.00001))], 10], {x, 0, 50}, {t, -50, 50}, {y, -50, -x}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 10]`

and then the answer is 2.738034446*10^-18!
Mathematica does not warn be about any issues in the computation, the calculations are done in seconds, so it seems like everything is ok, but the results differ by more than 20 orders of magnitude!
Anyone knows what is happening? And how should I deal with the singularity of my integral?

Edit: I must be able to compute the integral of the function Log [(y^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(y^2 + t^2 + m^2)]/ Log [(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] Exp[-(x + y)^2/( 2 0.00001)] as well, and the trick suggested in the answers does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't "jump" at `x=-y`, there is only a "continous peak"

Looking at the integrand I observe that you could separate the integration concerning y and t:

```
eps=1/100000;
inty = Integrate[Exp[-((x + y)^2/(2 eps))], {y, -50, 50}];
(* function of x and m *)

intt = Simplify[Integrate[Log[(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)] , {t, -50, 50}] - 
Integrate[Log[(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)] , {t,  -50, 50}], 
{Element[{x, m},Reals], x^2 + m^2 > 0, -50 <= x <= 50}]  
(* function of x and m*)
```

Now you can evaluate the remaining integral

```
int[m_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[intt inty , {x, -50, 50}]
```

which depends on m:

```
Plot[int[m], {m, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful!

Could you please explain to me what "m_?NumericQ" means?

Say I wanted to integrate from -l to l, instead of -50 to 50, so that the final result would depend on l as well. Then intt and inty would depend on m and l, and 

int[m_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[intt inty , {x, -l, l}] 

would give me a function of m and l?

Comment: Another question:
I  know that inty is a function of m and x. Say I want to convert it to a function of m and y, so that I can use it later without having to evaluate it again. Is that possible?

Comment: `m_?NumericQ `restricts the function argument to be numerical.That's why  NIntegrate is only called, if this condition is fullfilled. I'm not sure, wether I got your second question. x,y , are independent integration variables. I think it's not possible to convert x to y .

Comment: Btw, I need to compute a similar integral, but the function now is 
Log [(y^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(y^2 + t^2 + m^2)]/
 Log [(x^2 + t^2 + m^2 + 50^2)/(x^2 + t^2 + m^2)]  Exp[-(x + y)^2/(
  2 0.00001)], also for all variables ranging from -50 to 50. But I dont think that I can use your trick this time...
Should I ask another question or edit this one?

Comment: In this case only the integral over t is separable...I'm not sure wether the x,y integral converges.

Comment: I think it converges, the domain is finite and the functions are bounded.

Comment: I meant the convergence of NIntegrate in this case!